# Change ActionBar OverflowMenu Background color

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

Ive added a lot of properties to change to background color of the overflow menu, none seem to work.

Here are a few links i've refered (other than SO questions):

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1267
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

res>values>
**style.xml**

```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#28bda9</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#28bda9</item>
    </style>

    <!-- style the items within the overflow menu -->
    <style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">#28bda9</item>
    </style>

    <!-- style the list navigation -->
    <style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">#28bda9</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">#28bda9</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">#28bda9</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Edit: I have changed the code to match the solution. This was the error:**

```
<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">**#28bda9**</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but the `popupBackground` is not merely a color.

You have to change the drawable.

Below is the default drawable for Holo Light (usually called menu_dropdown_panel).

[image]

Change the color using your favorite image editor, and put it your drawable-x folder.

The needed style will be as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    ...
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Just edited the question: Something seems to be wrong: i tried the above solution

Comment: If you're using multiple values folders (values-v11, values-v14), make sure you're not overriding the styles in the other files.

Comment: v11 and v14 have default style.xml files

Comment: also tried to copy this style xml and past in the other two folders, that doesnt help either

Comment: My Bad. Cleaned the project, Works. :D